# How to protect Julia code from being read by users?

Tags: julia

Can Julia code be protected so that end users cannot read the code? I'm looking at this as alternative to Python which I know is difficult to protect.

I'm looking for a language which can be used to create end user desktop apps, which is strong in terms of statistics / mathematical applications, and Julia seems perfect for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two separate things you would need for such a scenario:

1. compile your code in an executable and ship the compiled code
2. "obfuscate" the code so that it becomes difficult to reverse engineer it

Honestly I don't think Julia is the most suited language for this task at this time:

(1) is possible with the [PackageCompiler.jl](https://github.com/JuliaLang/PackageCompiler.jl) package. It isn't however mainstream, don't expect a click and solve your problem solution.
For (2) I am not aware of software tools that obfuscate Julia source code, although you can still "decide" to write pretty cryptographic, spaghetti code in Julia if you wish!

Comment: Interesting thanks, is there another framework / language more suited to this in your opinion?

Comment: C and C# (and perhaps Java) have  tools for code obfuscation, if this is what you really need...

Answer (score 2):

You could certainly encrypt a file containing some of your code and then read the file, decrypt, Meta.parse(), and eval() that code in memory, FairPlay style.  That would keep anyone from simply browsing out of curiosity with an editor. But anyone with reasonable determination and some time could understand your method and decrypt your code.  Why bother?

Comment: Do you say "why bother" with Julia specifically, is there another framework / language more suited to this, or do you just mean in general, that all the available frameworks from C# to Xojo are all equally vulnerable?

Comment: As long as the code itself has to access the actual password I think any method of this type is potentially vulnerable.

Comment: @Bill basically the encryption approach is a lost effort by definition. The code would need to be run at some point and running it requires having AST in a decrypted state. Hence no matter how hard you try all this effort would be in vain.